# Apache X-Authorization request header

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, authorization, requestheader

I'm using Basic file type authorization in my Apache httpd configuration.

And my http request contains X-Authorization request header instead of Authorization.

I'm getting unauthorized error. How can I get my request authorized? What changes I should make in apache configurations?

I'm using apache 2.4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fix your HTTP request.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the control over the HTTP request.

Comment: Then whoever does control the HTTP request needs to fix it.